# friendly links with MVC and front controller

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, url-rewriting, front-controller

I have a jee project in which im using MVC and front controller design patterns.

I actually have all the links like this :

```
<a href="Controller?page=ForwardProducts">Products</a>
```

Or from javascript to make ajax calls:

```
Controller?page=AJAX&type=CheckID&_id=something
```

And a bit of code, whenever the links are pressed they go to a servlet that forwards info to the proper `.class` and receives the info (PD: the switch is bigger, just made it smaller):

```
        switch (request.getParameter("page")) {
            case "AJAX":
                String ajaxClass = request.getParameter("type");
                IAJAX _ajax = (IAJAX) Class.forName("my.package.Ajax." + ajaxClass).newInstance();
                String _json = _ajax.getJSON(request, response);
                try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
                    out.print(_json);
                }   
                break;
            default:
                ICommand _command = (ICommand) Class.forName("my.package.classes." + request.getParameter("page")).newInstance();
                _command.initPage(request, response);
                _includePage = _command.execute(request, response);
                request.getSession().setAttribute("_includePage", _includePage);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
                break;
        }
```

The ForwardAbout inside classes package looks like this:

```
public class ForwardAbout extends ICommand{
@Override
public void initPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

}

@Override
public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    return "/about.jsp";
}
}
```

And the ICommand:

```
public abstract class ICommand {

public void initPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

}

public abstract String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception;

}
```

I want to make pretty links, for example:

```
http://localhost:8084/testWeb/Controller?page=ForwardAbout
```

To

```
http://localhost:8084/testWeb/about-us
```

But also reverse, when an user writes `http://localhost:8084/testWeb/about-us` they should be redirected "internally" to `http://localhost:8084/testWeb/Controller?page=ForwardAbout`

I have tried http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ so that when the user writes the url they should be forwarded to the right content, but doesnt seem to work, got a lot of exceptions in the classes.

Is there any way to achieve this straight through code, without touching apache mods?

**PD:** due to "teaching purposes" as teacher said, we arent allowed to use any frameworks...

Comment: All real MVC frameworks allow doing that. You simply map the front controller to a URL pattern (/, or *.html, for example), and then map every action to a specfic URL. Then, in the from controller, instead of using a parameter to know which action to call, you use the URL. Don't reinvent the wheel. Use a real MVC framework (like Spring MVC, for example)

Comment: @JBNizet the lazy teacher told us not to use any frameworks xD, which makes the job even harder...

Comment: Then do how I described. Don't use a parameter to know which action to call. Use the URL.

Comment: @BalusC nope its not allowed but rather than reinventing the wheel...

Comment: @BalusC shoudnt be... how can i call a servlet without parameters? for example localhost/myweb/about coz this page can contain imports that depends on the parameter... In my case im allways redirecting to request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response); and then the index includes pages where needed from the parameter

Comment: @BalusC could this be achieved though javascript ? Would javascript be a viable solution ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76387/discussion-between-alpha2k-and-balusc).